# C# custom scripting language

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing a scripting language in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394180/implementing-a-scripting-language-in-c-sharp)

I have a C# app, now I want to allow users invoking some methods from my app, for example:

```
:step2
$test2=Click("post")
Wait()
IF($test2==1){
    runjs("mceRemoveControl")
    Form("post")
    $test3=Input("post_title","$TITLE")
    IF($test3==0){
        GOTO(step2)
    }
}
```

This is custom language which I want to parse in my app. Methods Click,runjjs,Input are methods from my C# program. Where I should looking for solution for such task?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Can you perhaps narrow it down to something more specific?

Comment: Maybe you should look into WCF (Web Services)

Comment: @ChrisGessler: And then he/she has 2 problems.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways.. just for starters:

If you want to stick with that funky syntax, start with http://www.antlr.org/ or similar parser generator or framework.

If you just want to have reasonable scripting language, not necessarily looking as the example, try IronRuby, IronPython or even JavaScript or C# (namespace CompilerServices allows you to compile code on the fly, then load it (possibly in separate appdomain to be able to unload it afterwards) and run)..

Edit: another thread with lots of links to parsers/compilercompilers: [What is a good C# compiler-compiler/parser generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194584/what-is-a-good-c-sharp-compiler-compiler-parser-generator)

Answer (score 2):

I found the book [Compiler Construction](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/CompilerConstruction/CompilerConstruction1.pdf) from Niklaus Wirth to be helpful for this type of task. Because we are talking about creating a compiler here. It is a small book that explains fundamental aspects of formal languages, explains the syntax description language EBNF and explains systematically how to write a compiler. Even if you have just an interpreter in mind. An interpreter can be considered as a special kind of compiler.

Be aware of the fact that this is not an easy task. You also might consider using a [compiler-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). An interesting alternative approach is provided by [Irony](https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony). Irony allows you to specify a language syntax directly in C# by using operator overloading.

Comment: Updated the links.